# ZMQ server/client pattern

Tags: c++, zeromq, communication

It is a general question about patterns used in `zmq`. I'm trying to achieve the following.

1. Client can connect to one server
2. Multiple clients connect to the same server
3. Server receives connections from multiple clients
4. Server processes multiple messages in parallel

Think of any webserver, just without all the HTTP stuff around it. The question is the [Paranoid Pirate Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Robust-Reliable-Queuing-Paranoid-Pirate-Pattern) a good candidate for such client/server? I guess it is a good idea to connect the backed socket to the workers using `inproc` since the queue and workers will be part of the same process, right? In case there is dozens to hundreds workers used, how should I work with the `zmq::context_t`? should I initiate it with high number of `io_threads` or use a `zmq::context_t` per worker?

EDIT001: Interestingly, `zmq` example of Paranoid Pattern does not work out of the box.

Comment: You can achieve that with a simple server socket. Zmq is overkill. Have a look at [asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html) instead, it's much easier to reason about.

Comment: I would personnaly use [this pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:mtserver) after reading your description :

Comment: @Clonk After all this is what I chose to use. Server side was the easiest part, just get request and forward to worker thread

Comment: @rustyx, apparently zmq wasnt overkill since requirements for client were growing exponentially but everything was relatively easily achieved using zmq patterns